# Reference Request - Lagrange Multipliers

Tags: calculus, analysis, reference-request, optimization, book-recommendation

What is a good source to learn about Lagrange Multipliers with proofs?

Comment: Bertsekas - Nonlinear Programming

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A very short but interesting paper:

[A proof of the method of Lagrange Multipliers.](http://www.math.cmu.edu/~gautam/sj/teaching/2016-17/269-vector-analysis/pdfs/lagrange.pdf)

The best:

> Before proving Theorem 1 we give an incorrect proof, that is found in many places.
> $$\cdots$$